# envirionment vairbales and scope

Tags: powershell, scope, environment-variables

This script is supposed to create some new drives but after i run it they dont exist, any ideas why? totally stuck....
Thanks in advance

```
Function New-Drives {

    Param()

        New-PSDrive -Name AppData -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $env:Appdata
        New-PSDrive -Name Temp -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $env
        $env:TEMP=Join-Path -Path C:\Windows\Temp
        $mydocs=Join-Path -Path $env:userprofile -ChildPath Documents
        New-PSDrive -Name Docs -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $mydocs

}

DIR temp: | measure-object –property length -sum

New-Drives
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the `-Persist` parameter to your `New-PSDrive` calls.  otherwise it will only create the drive within your powershell session.

Comment: You can not `-Persist` not single letter drives.

Comment: oh wow did not notice the multi-character names.  yea those cannot be mounted in Windows like that.  Powershell supports named drives but explorer and the rest of the OS will be looking for single drive letters.

Comment: Back to square one then? Can anyone answer this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  create a AppData:\ drive in explorer?  Windows won't allow you to do that.  If you'd like to create a y:\ (or any other unused letter) drive with a description of AppData in explorer that is possible, or if you want a function that creates a PS drive named AppData:\ that is usable in that PowerShell session that is also possible.

Comment: Thats it, just crate drives, okay, i think i get it now. Can use Letters, cool. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.